# Golang - get list of files from a shared Google Drive folder

Tags: go, google-drive-api

I am trying to list files and their IDs from a Google Drive folder using a known folder ID.

The drive service set up seems to be successful. But, I get a panic attempting to populate a variable with the info. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
    driveService, err := drive.NewService(ctx, option.WithCredentialsFile("../serverFiles/credentials.json"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Unable to retrieve Drive client: %v", err)
    }

    r, err := driveService.Files.List().
        DriveId('XXXXXXXXXX').
        PageSize(10).
        Fields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)").
        Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve files: %v", err)
    }
```

Here is the error I get:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x14312db]
```

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**
Thanks to @Tanaike's answer, I learned that I was confused about some points.
I am not attempting to get a list of files from a shared Drive, but a shared folder. 
I am using a service account to access. In another script the same service account is able to write to this same drive folder. So, I think permissions are OK. 
Here is how I am now trying to get the list (driveService is set up the same as above)

```
    r, err := driveService.Files.List().
        Corpora("user").
        PageSize(10).
        Q("'XXXXXXXX' in parents").
        Fields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)").
        Do()
```

I still get the panic and signal.

Comment: You might want to replace the `log.Printf()` with `log.Fatalf()`. As written you might be getting to the `r, err := ...` code with a `nil` value for `driveService` and crashing before the `log.Printf()` gets to flush its output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the file list from the shared drive using googleapis for go.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
r, err := driveService.Files.List().
    DriveId('XXXXXXXXXX').
    PageSize(10).
    Fields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)").
    Do()
```

#### To:

```
r, err := driveService.Files.List().
    DriveId("XXXXXXXXXX").
    Corpora("drive").
    SupportsAllDrives(true).
    IncludeItemsFromAllDrives(true).
    PageSize(10).
    Fields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)").
    Do()
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that you have permission for reading the shared drive and you have already been able to use Drive API. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)

Comment: I tried your suggested change; I get the same result.

Comment: @Roger Creasy Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `I tried your suggested change; I get the same result.`, unfortunately, when I tested my proposed script, I confirmed that the file list can be retrieved from the specific folder on the shared Drive. I deeply apologize that the script worked. But I would like to support you. So can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. By the way, in your situation, your service account has permission for reading the file metadata of the shared drive?

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Your answer taught me a couple of things. I was confusing DriveID and FolderID. I will edit my question with updates.

Comment: @Roger Creasy Thank you for replying. From `I was confusing DriveID and FolderID.`, in this case, you want to retrieve the specific folder which is not the shared Drive?

Comment: you are correct

Comment: @Roger Creasy Thank you for replying. In your additional script, when I tested it, no error occurs. The file list can be retrieved. And, I think that `Corpora("user")` can be removed in this case. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation of `I still get the panic and signal.`. For example, your shared folder is shared with the service account?

Comment: I had to recreate my service account json. I could not have solved this without your assistance. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Roger Creasy Thank you for replying and adding the information. I could understand your situation. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.